# Colouring components of ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, color, plot-themes

I am trying to use different colours to plot components of a `ContourPlot` in Mathematica. The contours are sufficiently complicated, such that I do not expect there to be a simple parametrisation. In my example

```
lim = 0.6; m = 1/6;
comp1 = -3 + 48 m^2 - 16 x - 128 m^2 x + 64 x^2 + 64 y^2;
comp2 = 81 m^2 - 1944 m^4 + 165888 m^8 - 27 x + 20736 m^4 x - 
   221184 m^6 x + 144 x^2 - 1728 m^2 x^2 + 27648 m^4 x^2 - 
   589824 m^6 x^2 - 576 x^3 - 36864 m^2 x^3 + 737280 m^4 x^3 + 
   6144 x^4 - 86016 m^2 x^4 + 688128 m^4 x^4 + 12288 x^5 - 
   786432 m^2 x^5 + 65536 x^6 - 262144 m^2 x^6 + 262144 x^7 - 
   2880 m^2 y^2 + 9216 m^4 y^2 + 589824 m^6 y^2 - 1344 x y^2 + 
   24576 m^2 x y^2 - 49152 m^4 x y^2 + 10240 x^2 y^2 - 
   303104 m^2 x^2 y^2 - 720896 m^4 x^2 y^2 + 40960 x^3 y^2 - 
   262144 m^2 x^3 y^2 + 131072 x^4 y^2 - 262144 m^2 x^4 y^2 + 
   786432 x^5 y^2 + 12288 m^2 y^4 + 688128 m^4 y^4 + 28672 x y^4 + 
   524288 m^2 x y^4 + 65536 x^2 y^4 + 262144 m^2 x^2 y^4 + 
   786432 x^3 y^4 + 262144 m^2 y^6 + 262144 x y^6;
c0 = ContourPlot[comp1 comp2 == 0, {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, ContourStyle -> Gray, ImageSize -> Small, 
   Axes -> True];
c1 = ContourPlot[comp1 == 0, {x, 0, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, 
   ContourStyle -> Blue];
c2 = ContourPlot[comp1 == 0, {x, -lim, 0}, {y, -lim, lim}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red];
Show[c0, c1, c2]
```

I study the zero locus of a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, with $m>0$ as a parameter. The contour has various intersection points that partitions it into (here 7) components. I would like to plot each of these components in a different colour. Since the polynomial factorises into `comp1` and `comp2`, this can be done for one factor `comp1`. In the picture, the blue and red components can be coloured by restricting the plotting domain. The other factor `comp2` contains multiple components, but does not factor for generic $m>0$ (also not for the chosen $m=\frac16$). I was wondering whether there is a trick to give the remaining 5 components belonging to `comp2` own colour. Many thanks for any suggestions!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hack that works for the example in OP: Use the option `Exclusions -> {x == 0}` to add a gap in contour lines at `x = 0` (which happens to be the intersection of the contours for `comp1 == 0` and `comp2 == 0` in this example), and post process to insert a different color before each line piece:

```
cp = ContourPlot[comp1 comp2 == 0, {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotPoints -> 150, Axes -> True, 
   Exclusions -> {x == 0}];

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[7];

Row[{cp, cp /. l_Line :> {Thick, Last[colors = RotateLeft[colors]], l}}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `comp2 == 0` to define an `ImplicitRegion` and use it with `RegionPlot` (which gives the correct number of multiple lines whereas `ContourPlot` of `comp2 == 0`  gives two closed curves):

```
impregion2 = ImplicitRegion[comp2 == 0, {{x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}}];

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[7]; 

Show[RegionPlot[impregion2, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-.6, .6}, {-.6, .6}}], 
  ContourPlot[comp1 == 0, {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, Axes -> True, Exclusions -> {x == 0}]] /. 
 l_Line :> {Thick, Last[colors = RotateLeft[colors]], l}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I would like to exclude further points (given by coordinates `{x,y}`from the level set), such that there are even more colours (I omitted this for simplicity of the question). Do you know how this can be done with `Exclusions`? Also, `Exclusions` produces quite large gaps around the excluded points, and the lines don't touch the excluded points. Would you know how this can be fixed?