# Excluding points from 2d plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot certain regions using `ContourPlot` and `RegionPlot` in two dimensions. From these implicitly defined contours I need to exclude certain points. In the documentation of `Exclusions` it says that for a domain defined by $n$ variables, exclusions must be of dimension $n-1$. Since points are dimension 0 objects, it does not work to exclude them naively. My idea to circumvent this issue was to include short line segments through the points and exclude the lines instead, which would not be a problem with my plot. However, I do not find anywhere how this can be done. An example for a plot can be found in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246658/colouring-components-of-contourplot). Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: can you add an example list of {x,y} pairs you want exclude  from `ContourPlot[comp2 ==0,...]`?

Comment: {2m^2 - 1/8,0} and {m^2+1/8,0} in that particular example. Perhaps one could exclude a short line through each of these points that would intersect with the curve only in the points...?